# What command converts knitr R Markdown into Stack-Exchange-friendly Markdown?

Tags: r, knitr

**Motivation**:
I often want to paste the results of a quick analysis using R Markdown into a StackExchange site. This includes the [R-tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), or even a domain specific analysis on sites like [Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) (e.g., this quick analysis of [OECD life index data](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/922/what-is-the-correlation-between-objective-indexes-and-aggregated-self-report-mea/1067#1067)).

**Problems with default conversion:**
The **default** markdown output of `knitr` is not suitable for inclusion on StackExchange.
The main problems I can see are that

- images are referenced to the local hard drive
- code chunks are not tab or space indented; rather they use github style Markdown (i.e., no indentation)

I.e., the chunks look like this:

````
```r
some code
```
````

and output looks like this

````
```
## some output
## ...
```
````

There might also be other specific issues to consider, such as

- ensuring tables are included properly
- ensuring that equations are passed correctly for sites that support MathJax like Cross Validated and Cognitive Science Stack Exchange.

#### Question

**What is a good command for converting R Markdown into Markdown (or HTML) suitable for simple inclusion into Stack Exchange sites?**

I think an ideal command would be a one-liner that takes an R Markdown file and generates a file where the entire content can be pasted directly into Stack Exchange to yield a well-formatted question or answer.

I share [this simple rmd file](https://github.com/downloads/jeromyanglim/assorted-files/non-sig-r.rmd) with a couple of code chunks, a figure, and an equation as a test example.

**Initial thoughts**:
Hosting of images on imgur would presumably sort out the issue with images. This can be done by including the following in the R Markdown file, but it would probably be simpler if this instruction was incorporated into some one-liner command.

`````
``` {r }
opts_knit$set(upload.fun = imgur_upload) 
````
`````

It might be worth considering whether HTML or Markdown is the better format for pasting into  StackExchange. The `markdown` package provides a lot of flexibility.

Comment: wow, approaching University of Stack Exchange here. Does arXiv have this kind of support, even?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a utility function that should get you started. It sets auto uploads to imgur, as well as markdown rendering of source code using tabs instead of fenced blocks. You can enhance this function to add other options that would be useful.

```
stackify <- function(rmd_file, ...){
  require(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(upload.fun = imgur_upload) 
  render_markdown(strict = TRUE)
  out <- knit(rmd_file, ...)
  return(invisible(out))
}
```

UPDATE: I tested this function on your test file, and it renders well on stats.stackexchange.com which is `mathjax` enabled.

Comment: Thanks. That works quite well. One thing that I think could be improved is the amount of space between input and output. With the above function there are three blank lines between R commands and R output and it is all rendered as one large code chunk. That's too much white space for stack exchange. I think ideally output on stackexchange would look similar to how it does by default (i.e., white box for input and grey box for output).  At the very least I think one blank line between input and output is sufficient.

Comment: Good point. I am not sure why the extra newlines appear. You might want to post this as an issue on `knitr` mailing list or github.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's an issue with knitr or not. It might have something to do with how StackExchange renders markdown. The blank lines are not tab indented. So I imagine in theory the code blocks should not merge together, but they do in StackExchange.

Comment: Extra newlines are there to make sure the blocks are well separated, because extra newlines do not hurt in markdown.

Comment: Makes sense. But it creates a problem when you use `results = "asis"`, since the extra newlines also get printed along with it.

Answer (score 4):

Although I'd still like to read other suggestions I hacked together this script using @Ramnath's answer as a starting point. It outputs a HTML fragment rather than Markdown.

```
Rscript -e 'rmd_file <- dir(pattern="rmd"); md_file <- sub("rmd", "md", rmd_file); html_file <- sub("rmd", "html", rmd_file); require(methods); require(knitr); require(markdown); opts_knit$set(upload.fun = imgur_upload); knit(rmd_file); markdownToHTML(md_file, html_file, options="fragment_only") '
```

- It assumes that there is a single `rmd` file in the working directory. I imagine that selecting the rmd file could be done in a more sophisticated way.
- It requires that the `knitr` and `markdown` packages are installed.
- I think because we are using 'Rscript' the `methods` package needs to be loaded.
- It uploads images to imgur
- markdownToHTML exports only the code fragment as a html file. The contents of this file can then be copied into the Stack Exchange answer.

The result looks pretty good. It overcomes the issue of excessive blank lines. However, the output is not markdown, which makes the result harder to edit.

Answer (score 1):

RStudio uses pandoc and so you can specify the markdown variant suitable for your needs. At the start of the .Rmd file:

```
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_strict+autolink_bare_uris
---
```

You should then be able to copy/paste the resulting file contents into StackExchange.

See: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/markdown_document_format.html#markdown-variants