# Delete column when rows contain same character

Tags: r

I have a matrix of character/number combinations, and I need to delete those columns wherein the same character appears in both rows of the column. For a simplified example:

```
> chars <- c("A1","A2","B1","B2")
> charsmat <- combn(chars, 2)
> charsmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "A1" "A1" "A1" "A2" "A2" "B1"
[2,] "A2" "B1" "B2" "B1" "B2" "B2"
```

When both rows of a single column contain the same character (in this case, columns 1 and 6), I need to delete that column. I feel like I have the pieces: use `gsub()` or `str_extract()` to isolate the characters, and test if there's a match between rows, but I'm stuck as to how to enact it. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a new matrix with only the alphabetic part extracted:

```
> (charsmat.alpha <- substr(charsmat, 0, 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"
```

Then, get the subset of columns from `charsmat` where the two rows of `charsmat.alpha` are not the same:

```
> charsmat[,(charsmat.alpha[1,] != charsmat.alpha[2,])]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A1" "A1" "A2" "A2"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B1" "B2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general solution, that will remove columns in which *any letter*  in the row 1 entry matches *any letter* in the row 2 entry:

```
## Your data
chars <- c("A1","A2","B1","B2")
charsmat <- combn(chars, 2)

vetMatrix <- function(mat) {
    ## Remove non-alpha characters from matrix entries
    mm <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", mat)    
    ## Construct character class regex patterns from first row
    patterns <- paste0("[", mm[1,], "]")
    xs <- mm[2,]    
    ## Extract columns in which no character in first row is found in second
    mat[,!mapply("grepl", patterns, xs), drop=FALSE]
}

## Try it with your matrix ...
vetMatrix(charsmat)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A1" "A1" "A2" "A2"
# [2,] "B1" "B2" "B1" "B2"

## ... and with a different matrix
mat <- matrix(c("AB1", "B1", "AA11", "BB22", "this", "that"), ncol=3) 
mat
#      [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,] "AB1" "AA11" "this"
# [2,] "B1"  "BB22" "that"
vetMatrix(mat)
#     [,1]  
# [1,] "AA11"
# [2,] "BB22"
```

Comment: Do you construct a response like this with the results of statements commented after the statements automatically?

Comment: Do you have a program that will take `mat` and `vetMatrix(mat)` and spit out the bottom eight lines of your answer, with the results of the two statements interleaved as comments?

Comment: @MichaelHoffman -- Gotcha. I usually use emacs, which allows me to highlight a region of R output and type `M-x r t` and then `<space><space><space><space>#<space>` to prepend it with four spaces, a `#` and then one more space. I can then copy it with `M-w` and paste into SO.  For shorter blocks like this one, I often just paste in results from the console and use SO's `{}` button to indent, then comment out by hand.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman, you _could_ use `knitr`. See this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068603/what-command-converts-knitr-r-markdown-into-stack-exchange-friendly-markdown)