# Possible to generate MediaWiki Markup from knitr?

Tags: r, mediawiki, knitr, wiki, markup

I am producing a report which will be published in pdf format. It concerns statistics and particularly the use of R. Therefore I am using knitr. I would also like to publish it to a wiki, with minimal extra effort by me!

Is it possible to get wiki markup (MediaWiki) output from knitr?

Or, if I generate HTML from knitr, can HTML be given directly to the wiki?

This problem is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068603/what-command-converts-knitr-r-markdown-into-stack-exchange-friendly-markdown). Wiki markup rules are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext), but I can't quite see if full HTML is supported.

Thanks.

Comment: I think pandoc can convert markdown to MediaWiki markup ( http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html ); if you can install pandoc you should be able to get a reasonable first draft, but the devil will be in the details ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly define the markup rules in `knitr` output hooks: http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks As one simple example, you can highlight source code with `<syntaxhighlight>`:

```
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  sprintf('<syntaxhighlight lang=%s>%s</syntaxhighlight>', options$engine, x)
})
```

You are free to design the rest of the output hooks. But as Ben Bolker pointed out, I think you are better off with Markdown, and convert that to Mediawiki via Pandoc.

Comment: Cool, I'll go down the markdown > mediawiki route through Pandoc for now. And I'll look into defining a set of mediawiki hooks on a rainy day!

Comment: @bdh_dtu Nice. I'll look forward to a Github pull request from you when it rains.